# RewriteCond doesn't let my IP address through

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to restrict access to my dev site to just my IP address.  (eg `123.123.123.123`)

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file.  However I still get redirected to `/dev_site_notice.html`.

Am I specifying this correctly?

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/dev_site_notice.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /dev_site_notice.html [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
> RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123
> ```

If you are checking for the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header in the `SetEnvIf` directive then it implies you are behind a proxy server (otherwise this directive should be removed). If this is the case then the `REMOTE_ADDR` server variable is the IP address of the proxy, not the client IP address.

If (and only if) you are behind a proxy then you should be checking the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP request header instead. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For} !^123\.123\.123\.123($|\D)
```

Note that the `X-Forwarded-For` header can contain multiple (comma-separated) IP addresses, depending on whether the request has gone through several proxies. The client-IP is usually first (left-most), but you may need to confirm this with the proxy. For this reason, the regex should not end with `$` (not that your original regex did anyway), but rather `($|\D)` (end-of-string OR *not* a digit).

The `X-Forwarded-For` header is the defacto standard, but it can vary from proxy to proxy. It is the proxy server that sets this header, when the request passes through.

Comment: thank you!  The server is indeed behind a proxy server.  Such a clear and concise and informative answer - makes me want to now learn more about how to use htaccess.